# Difference between increasing join window size and setting grace period

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

How would the join output differ, when comparing

```java
JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(a)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(b))
```

and

```java
JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(a + b))
```

Answer (score 2):

The window duration affects how far apart records can be, and still be part of the same "group". Grace period affects how far apart records can arrive out of order, and still be part of that group. To really understand it, we need to grasp the impact of stream time and wall clock time.

**Different kinds of time**

Kafka uses a so-called "stream time" concept, which is a strictly increasing timestamp based on the event time of the incoming records. In the words of [Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers/):

> Wall-clock time advances because that little quartz watch in your computer keeps ticking away, but stream time only advances when you get new records. With no new records, stream time is frozen.

**Example**

Let's look at a simplified scenario with a single topic. Records are arriving with the *event time* and *stream time* as shown. The *order* in which the events arrive is important, but the actual wall clock time is not relevant.

```
Event1 @ 0s // Stream time 0s
Event2 @ 2s // Stream time 2s
Event3 @ 5s // Stream time 5s
Event4 @ 3s // Stream time still 5s
Event5 @ 6s // Stream time 6s
```

**Window of 5 seconds, grace period of 0 seconds**

Let's say we use a join window of 5 seconds. `Event1` opens a new window. `Event2`, `Event3`, `Event4` are then added to the window. `Event5` cannot be added to the window, and there is no grace period, so the first window is closed and a second window starts.

End result:

1. Window with `Event1`, `Event2`, `Event3`, `Event4`
2. Window with `Event5`

**Window of 4 seconds, grace period of 1 second**

Now, we use a shorter window, but with a grace period. `Event1` and `Event2` form the first window. `Event3` cannot be added to the window, because it is more than 4 seconds ahead. so `Event3` starts a new window. However, it does not immediately close the first window, because there is a grace period. The first window remains open for a total of `4 + 1 = 5` seconds of event time. When `Event4` arrives, it is still part of the first window. When `Event5` arrives, the grace period has passed, the first window is closed, and `Event5` is added to the second window.

End result:

1. Window with `Event1`, `Event2`, `Event4`
2. Window with `Event3`, `Event5`

Comment: really nice explanation! what would happen if there is `Event6 @ 3s  // Stream time still 6s` coming in? since the grace period has passed, does it open yet another window "in the past"?

Comment: In that case `Event6` would be discarded, because the stream join has already emitted its result for the first window.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one particular test case comparing a 0 and 1ms windows. The grace periods tested (0, 1ms, 1000ms) did not affect the outcome.

| t1 | t2 | window=0ms | window=1ms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1 / - | 1 / - |
|  | 3 | - / 3 | - / 3 |
| 2 |  | 2 / - | 2 / 3 |
|  | 4 | - / 4 | - / 4 |
| 3 |  | 3 / 3 | 3 / 3 |
|  |  |  | 3 / 4 |
|  | 5 | - / 5 | - / 5 |
| 4 |  | 4 / 4 | 4 / 3 |
|  |  |  | 4 / 4 |
|  |  |  | 4 / 5 |
|  | 6 | - / 6 | - / 6 |

- t1 is topic #1, t2 is topic #2
- the entries in the t1 / t2 columns are the timestamps embedded in the record values, and they will be used for joining via a `TimestampExtractor`